# Why netcat port forwarding can just receive one time connection?

Tags: bash, netcat

1. I have one http server open 8000 port like next:

   ```
   orange@orange:~$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer
   Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
   ```
2. As known to all, there are several versions netcat, but for some reasons, I can just use next versions:

   ```
   root@orange:~# busybox nc
   BusyBox v1.27.2 (Ubuntu 1:1.27.2-2ubuntu3.2) multi-call binary.

   Usage: nc [-iN] [-wN] [-l] [-p PORT] [-f FILE|IPADDR PORT] [-e PROG]

   Open a pipe to IP:PORT or FILE

   -l      Listen mode, for inbound connects
           (use -ll with -e for persistent server)
   -p PORT Local port
   -w SEC  Connect timeout
   -i SEC  Delay interval for lines sent
   -f FILE Use file (ala /dev/ttyS0) instead of network
   -e PROG Run PROG after connect
   ```

   This means only above parameters should be used.
3. I did next:

   ```
   root@orange:~# rm -f /tmp/backpipe && mkfifo /tmp/backpipe && cat /tmp/backpipe | busybox nc 127.0.0.1 8000 | busybox nc -l -p 80 > /tmp/backpipe
   ```

   The aim is: when user visit `http://127.0.0.1:80`, it will automactically forward to `http://127.0.0.1:8000`, so the contents of `python simplehttpserver` will returned to user.
4. Finally, I launch test client:

   ```
   orange@orange:~$ wget http://127.0.0.1
   --2019-06-26 22:47:25--  http://127.0.0.1/
   Connecting to 127.0.0.1:80... connected.
   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
   Length: 1378 (1.3K) [text/html]
   Saving to: ‘index.html’

   index.html                              100% 
   [==============================================>]   1.35K  --.-KB/s    in 0s
   2019-06-26 22:47:25 (505 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [1378/1378]
   ```
5. Above all ok, but back to the port forward command, I found it had been exit, so it nolonger receive the second time connect.

So, my question is, with above busybox netcat, how can I make this port forward command not exit after the first connection.

NOTE: I don't want the solution with `for-loop`, I just want to find the way to do port forward with above netcat, meanwhile it will continue serve after the first connection.

Comment: Because how else would the program behave? If it refuses to close the remote connection, then it should also keep the forwarded connection open forever, and ultimately cause the server to run out of ports.

Comment: Sorry, I did not catch you, in fact I'm not quite familar with `netcat`, but what I wanted just similar as next `socat TCP4-LISTEN:30000,reuseaddr,fork TCP4:1.1.1.1:30000`, forward all connection to 30000 to the new ip 1.1.1.1's 30000 port, and I know this works, and this will continue serve for ever. But now I had to use netcat...

Comment: Then use `socat`, or a dedicated web server. Apache in reverse proxy mode would do wha you ask; I'm guessing `nginx` has a similar feature. You can't really write a scalable, robust internet server as a shell script oneliner (unless then that one line calls something capable).

Comment: Thanks, in fact I am in a Alpine docker container with just netcat preinstall, I don't want to install anything in entrypoint or cmd as it is ugly, and it disable root, I can use -u root to enter it with root but too complex. also I have to use the running container so I cannot extend my own dockerfile. So I come here to find if easy way with netcat could make me quick do this.

Comment: And , if netcat port forward cannot serve forever, Then it more like a toy at least in this scenario. I doubt this, as its so famous

Comment: Running it in a loop would do more or less what you ask, but you explicitly rule out that option. If you don't have a good reason to avoid a loop, go with that (but still don't expect the server to reliably handle many clients in parallel).

Comment: `netcat` is a very useful client, and it can do some things pretty well server-side, too; but you are pushing its limits here.

Comment: you can try `ncat` from nmap package, which offers more functionality than most implementations of netcat available

Answer (score 0):

You may have been using an older version of busybox. Current versions come with the `-lk` flag, which allows you to persist the server beyond just a single connection.

In order to accomplish what you wanted, you can do something like this:

```
busybox nc -lk -p 80 -e busybox nc localhost 8000
```